# Rails Tutorial - ERROR MESSAGE: expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>

Tags: railstutorial.org

The test in "Listing 8.20: A test for user logging in with valid information" is giving me a persistent error message:

```
 FAIL["test_login_with_valid_information", UsersLoginTest, 1.051300315]
 test_login_with_valid_information#UsersLoginTest (1.05s)
 Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
 test/integration/users_login_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

The test is:

```
19   test "login with valid information" do
20    get login_path
21    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
22    assert_redirected_to @user
23    follow_redirect!
24    assert_template 'users/show'
25    ....
```

The Sessions controller is what I am imagining is causing this error message

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    log_in user
    redirect_to user  # What I want to happen
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'      # What is happening
  end
end
```

If the user is authenticated, it should **redirect** to the users profile page
else the login form will **render**

So the problem I believe is that my test user is not being authenticated. The application login and redirect functions just fine when I login manually on the site.

**test/fixtures/users.yml** has this to pass the password 'password'

```
   password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

and the user model has this to digest the password 'password'

```
 def User.digest(string)
  cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                              BCrypt::Engine.cost
  BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
 end
```

Where does the problem lie? and further more how can I make another test that shows me why this test is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a good nights sleep I realized it was likely due to a database error. Low and behold my database had a capitalized email and my controller submits a downcased email.

Solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar (identical) issue if I'm reading this right and for the sake of clarity for future browsers I'll add the following: As Shonin pointed out the issue has to do with the controller taking downcase email addresses and so apparently in users.yml the code

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: Michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Will not pass while

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Will pass.